# How to set android screen value in fragment from Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, tabs

I have a fragment that implements a RootView from an xml file definition. The xml file has a spinner called diceSpinner1, a radionButtonGroup called radioOddEven1, and a button that performs a rollDice activity. How do I get diceSpinner1 and radioButtonGroup in the rollDice activity?

UPDATE: I changed DestinationsFragment.java and got rid of RoleDice to solve my problem.

DestinationsFragment.java

```
public class DestinationsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.destinations, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rollDiceButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDetail();
          }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    public void updateDetail() {
        setDiceSpinner(3);
        setOddEven(1);
    }
    public void setDiceSpinner(int value) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.diceSpinner1);
        spinner.setSelection(value);
    }
    public void setOddEven(int value) {
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioOddEven1);
        if (value == 0) {
            rg.check(R.id.radioOdd1);
        }else {
            rg.check(R.id.radioEven1);
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat output

```
11-27 23:19:17.360: D/dalvikvm(2456): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 5% free 3138K/3296K, paused 95ms, total 100ms
11-27 23:19:17.400: I/dalvikvm-heap(2456): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.206MB for 1127536-byte allocation
11-27 23:19:17.490: D/dalvikvm(2456): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 4237K/4400K, paused 86ms, total 87ms
11-27 23:19:18.010: I/System.out(2456): android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{b1d50eb0 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090000 app:id/pager}
11-27 23:19:18.020: I/System.out(2456): com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl@b1d51e30
11-27 23:19:18.020: I/System.out(2456): 0
11-27 23:19:20.160: D/gralloc_goldfish(2456): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-27 23:19:21.620: I/Choreographer(2456): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 23:19:25.080: D/dalvikvm(2456): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 98K, 4% free 4652K/4820K, paused 200ms, total 218ms
11-27 23:19:25.470: D/AndroidRuntime(2456): Shutting down VM
11-27 23:19:25.470: W/dalvikvm(2456): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a44b90)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456): Process: com.njb.rblookup, PID: 2456
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.njb.rblookup/com.njb.rblookup.RollDice}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at com.njb.rblookup.RollDice.onCreate(RollDice.java:23)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-27 23:19:25.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2456):     ... 11 more
11-27 23:19:37.440: I/Process(2456): Sending signal. PID: 2456 SIG: 9
```

RollDice.java

```
 public class RollDice extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
        View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.destinationsTab);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.diceSpinner1);
        spinner.setSelection(3);
        RadioGroup rbg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioOddEven1);
        rbg.check(R.id.radioEven1);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.roll_dice, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

destinations.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/destinationsTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioOddEven1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioOdd1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_odd" 
                android:checked="true" 
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioEven1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_even" />

        </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/diceLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dice_total_prompt"
                />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/diceSpinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/dice_value_array"
            android:prompt="@string/dice_total_prompt" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rollDiceButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/roll_dice_button" 
            android:onClick="rollDice"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

    public final static String ODD_EVEN_VALUE = "com.njbRailbaronlookup.ODD_EVEN_VALUE";
    public final static String DICE_VALUE = "com.njbRailbaronlookup.DICE_VALUE";
    public final static String REGION_VALUE = "com.njbRailbaronlookup.REGION_VALUE";
    public final static String CITY_1_VALUE = "com.njbRailbaronlookup.CITY_1_VALUE";
    public final static String CITY_2_VALUE = "com.njbRailbaronlookup.CITY_2_VALUE";

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Destinations", "Payouts" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        System.out.println(viewPager);
        System.out.println(tab);
        System.out.println(tab.getPosition());
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
    public void rollDice(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RollDice.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

DestinationsFragment.java

```
public class DestinationsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.destinations, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the **line**' number **23** in `RollDice`

Comment: spinner.setSelection(3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start `RollDice` activity as a normal activity and you have never passed the view via `Intent` not set the `Layout` for the RollDice acitivity. thus you ar egetting the error.

UPDATE: Read this [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) get how fragment works.

```
public class RollDice extends Fragment{
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, container, false);

        // DO what you want with the RollDice
        return rootView;
    }
  // add other stuff
}
```

on Tab select attach this fragment with main FragmentActivity.

If you are not able to get then please go through this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html).

Comment: How do I pass the view in the intent?

Comment: which layout you are going to display in your `RollDice` as `RollDice` si not a fragment or fragmentActivity.

Comment: I want to set the value of diceSpinner1 in the destinations tab, which is the same screen that invokes the RollDice Activity.

Comment: so why are you use RollDice as Activity, make it Fragment and invoke it.

Comment: Sorry, new to Android. Any sites that have examples of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Thanks Yup. Getting rid of the RollDice activity and changing the DestinationsFragment did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a layout in the onCreate() of your RollDice using setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutname) with those viewsu have mentioned.Thasts why you are getting the null point exception.

Comment: when I add setContentView(R.layout.destinations); to the onCreate() of RollDice, it works the first time, but the next time I click the button, I get this error

Comment: 11-28 00:14:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(2896): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method rollDice(View) in the activity class com.njb.rblookup.RollDice for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'rollDiceButton'